# "perform create index" in plpgsql doesn't run

Tags: postgresql, sql-injection, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I'm having problems executing a "perform create index" inside of a plgpsql function (postgres 9.4). For example:

```
create or replace function foo() returns void language plpgsql as $$ 
begin 
  perform 'create unique index patients_row_id_key on patients(row_id)'; 
end; $$;
```

It seems to run fine:

```
select foo();
```

However, the index is not created. Any diagnosis and workaround? I tried:

```
alter function foo() VOLATILE;
```

and still no luck.

Comment: Ah -- great: I thought that "execute" was ruled out because there is no result value. Enter as answer and I will accept....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PERFORM` statement in the PLPGSQL used to execute queries which does not return result or which result is not useful. Technically `PERFORM ...` inside the PLPGSQL block is equal to `SELECT ...` in the plain SQL. So in your example you are trying to execute something like

```
select 'create unique index patients_row_id_key on patients(row_id)';
```

and just ignore the result.

Read more: [Executing a Command With No Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT)

You should not to wrap DDL statements inside PLPGSQL and can use it as is:

```
create or replace function foo() returns void language plpgsql as $$ 
begin 
  create unique index patients_row_id_key on patients(row_id);
end; $$;
```

Or if you want to construct it at runtime then use EXECUTE statement: [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) like this:

```
create or replace function foo(p_tablename text) returns void language plpgsql as $$ 
begin 
  execute 'create unique index ' || p_tablename || '_row_id_key on ' || p_tablename || '(row_id)';
end; $$;
```

Comment: [As @Chris explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38021245/939860), your suggested function is not safe against SQL injection.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It was just a quick example for the `execute` statement usage. In the real life such service functions should be restricted for execution by regular users. IMO.

Comment: Restricting functions to regular users is hardly a solution to the problem. Table names (and other identifiers) have to be treated like user input at all times. Else, if a trusting user runs through tables of a schema, the bare existence of such a table is a ticking bomb.

Answer (score 4):

As a supplement to the point of using execute, note two important points about this.

1. You are doing string interpolation with sql queries (dangerous!), and
2. You have to use quote_ident, not quote_literal

If you use Abelisto's function above, and call it with:

```
SELECT foo('test_idx on test; drop table foo; --');
```

SQL injection in stored procedure.  Worse if it is security definer.  A fixed version would be:

```
create or replace function foo(p_tablename text) returns void language plpgsql as $$ 
begin 
  execute 'create unique index ' || quote_ident(p_tablename || '_row_id_key') || ' on ' || quote_ident(p_tablename) || '(row_id)';
end; $$;
```

Comment: NB the function I gave as an example didn't take any parameters at all -- just a made up example of course because I wanted to ask about "perform". Real code (which uses quote_ident for identities) is much more involved.

Comment: I recognize that. The reason to discuss it was that the solution offered used parameters and that is dangerous in part for those who may read it in a year.

Answer (score 4):

[What @Abelisto wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38018107/939860) about `PERFORM`.
And [what @Chris added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021245/939860) about SQL injection.

Plus, I suggest to use `format()` for anything except the most trivial query strings to make your life with dynamic SQL easier. [And the manual does, too:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

> A cleaner approach is to use `format()`'s `%I` specification for table or column names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(_tbl text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$ 
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE format('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX %I ON %I(row_id)', _tbl || _row_id_key', _tbl);
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

A `regclass` parameter is a convenient alternative for passing table names, but concatenating new identifiers can be tricky - as this recent related case goes to show:

- [PL/pgSQL regclass quoting of table named like keyword](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141113/pl-pgsql-regclass-quoting-of-table-named-like-keyword/141680#141680)